# Does amqp support flow control with producerMaxRate

Tags: jboss-amq

I am using Red Hat JBoss AMQ 7.1.0.GA and testing flow control with amqp protocol by using example under amq71Install\examples\protocols\amqp\queue, I just added producerMaxRate=1 in the following code sample:

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new JmsConnectionFactory("amqp://192.168.56.11:61616?producerMaxRate=1");
```

But this doesn't works on controlling the flow, is it possible to use this parameter for amqp protocol?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "producerMaxRate" parameter is only valid for "core" JMS clients, not AMQP.